# Can I use a busbar as a ground in my travel trailer?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I need to ground my inverter and a few other items from my fuse box. Can I use a single busbar, mounted to the floor, as a ground. If not, can you offer suggestions?

Comment: I can't tell if you're serious, or joking...  Is the floor bonded to the main grounding conductor? Does the floor provide an electrical path to ground?

Comment: That's a GREAT question.  How do you handle grounding in a vehicle?

Comment: NEC 551 covers trailers. 551.30 allows generators to be bonded to the frame or chassis. 551.32 covers inverters, generators and says must be listed for use in RV and comply with the rest of the article parts 1,2,3,4&5.

Comment: What are these "few other items"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bus bar, yes.

But you should never assume that the entire trailer is bonded together in such a way that you can use any of it separately as a connection to the bus bar.

Think of how many pieces it takes to build the trailer.  Screws rust and aluminum reacts to the oxygen in the atmosphere to produce resistance.  That's the last thing you want in a ground system.

So if you use a bus bar, be sure that your "things" are grounded directly to it, and that you have a good thick copper wire connection between the bus bar and the service entrance.